# Cross Domain Ajax, same server but different port?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, solr, cross-domain

I am new to AJAX and trying to learn.  I have setup a Java servlet running on port 8983 which returns XML search results from a database when queried.  I am also running a wamp server on port 80 and trying to get these search results to show up on the page.  I assuming I am encountering this cross domain ajax call problem even though it's the same host, because I'm running these services on 2 separate ports?

I heard the solution is to use jsonp to wrap the response form the servlet in a function.  The problem is, I don't think I can do this since this servlet is Apache Solr and I've just configured it and am running it out of the box.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make SOLR accept JSONP requests, according to http://xplus3.net/2010/09/21/solr-and-jsonp/

Comment: You also need to instruct Solr to return the response in JSON format as the default is XML, but this can be done with the simple querystring parameter `wt=json` which is supported out the box, so you should not have any issues. See this example - http://skipperkongen.dk/2011/01/11/solr-with-jsonp-with-jquery/

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I am now able to retrieve Jsonp from my solr server.  I just have to learn how to process it (I have only learned javascript but all the examples are in jquery).